# Webpack doesn't respect 'module' field in package.json

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, package.json, dead-code, tree-shaking

I am trying to figure out **tree-shaking** in **Webpack** and I noticed that running `-webpack -optimize-minimize` on this **Example1** is 11kB, while on **Example2** it is 7kB.

The library `Rambda` has a field **module** in its `package.json`. As far as I can see **Webpack** doesn't respect it and I need to explicitly refer to the `esm` file location.

The question is that a bug or a feature?

**Example1**

```
import {add} from 'rambda'

function fn(x) {
  return add(2)(x)
}
console.log(fn(3))
```

**Example2**

```
import {add} from 'rambda/dist/rambda.esm.js'

function fn(x) {
  return add(2)(x)
}
console.log(fn(3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this is a documented bug - https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4674

> What is the current behavior?
>   When module's package.json contains browser, module & main fields, webpack is bundling browser build by default.

The bug is unresolved for 6 months so the solution is ugly - remove **browser** field from `package.json`, so `Webpack` can use **module** field.

Comment: How do you remove `browser` field for a `node_modules` dependency ? patch-package ? Are you sure it will work ?